# Why can't I append 2 dimension list vertically? The last list effects all element

Tags: python

I am coding by using **python**. I just want to append this two lists. So, I want to make this(below current). these variables( past, curent) are not constant. I mean that their size are changeable. And, according to their size, the number of iteration is also changeable.

First iteration

past(1)=

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Second iteration

past(2)=

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

(I want to make this)

curent=

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 1, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1], 
[0, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I wrote "current.append(past)"
Because of "**call by reference**", 
current variable was below my variable

Error

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1], 
[0, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1], 
[0, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

How can I prevent call by reference?
Simply speaking, I just want [past1, past2, past3,...].
But,  because of call by reference, I made [lastPast, lastPast, lastPast,...]
I cannot use numpy.
As you can see, I just want append 2 dimension list vertically.

Comment: current += past . what you want is to concatenate the lists

Comment: your current code adds a list of lists into current. 

there are two main ways to add parts of lists.

`[1,2,3] + [4,5,6] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`
`[1,2,3,4,5].append(6) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Notice that with `+` the two parameters are both lists, while with `append` the parameter is the type of the elements in the list